# Warning: Skipping shivammathur/php/php: most recent version 8.2.0 not installed

Tags: php, homebrew, php-8.2

Why am I getting the message "Warning: Skipping shivammathur/php/php: most recent version 8.2.0 not installed in Homebrew?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove this warning and install 8.2.0, run:

```
brew unlink php

brew tap shivammathur/php

brew install shivammathur/php/php@8.2
```

Then check your PHP version.

```
php -v
```

> PHP 8.2.0 (cli) (built: Dec  8 2022 03:36:07) (NTS) Copyright (c) The
> PHP Group Zend Engine v4.2.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
> with Zend OPcache v8.2.0, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

Comment: I needed to do `brew link php@8.2` for this to work for me.